# Ubuntu Server and OpenVPN Client, SSH ACCES!

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, openvpn

i have instance on google cloud, it's running ubuntu server 18.04 LTS, i setup openvpn, and as soon as i connect it drops me out of SSH. i'am running nordvpn, i know port forwarding is not allowed, but is there a way to make it work to my origin IP adress to ssh?

MY PUBLIC IP IS: 35.246.229.999
MY eth0 is: 10.156.0.39
and loopback: 127.0.0.1

and VPN ip let's guess 89.9.8.1  (i doubt that's needed now)

Well how to set this up?
i has to do something with ip route, i just can't get it straight!, all this default gateway ,subnets, i'am noob, can someone help me set this up?

Comment: Also not even :80 (web) does not work on origin ip if i connect to vpn!

Comment: Allright, i've tried adding 
ip rule add from 35.234.124.45 table 128
ip route add table 128 to 35.234.124.45 dev ethX
ip route add table 128 default via 10.156.0.1 , this should be able added after VPN connects?, so i've tried running openvpn --up myscript.sh --config client.ovpn and myscript.sh has that commands, but after it executes it nordvpn adds again custom route and i dropout :(

Comment: Connecting to a VPN changes your routes, so loss of an existing SSH session over those older routes seems like expected behavior. If your OpenVPN server is set up properly, you should be able to connect to VPN first, then begin an SSH session using the new routes.

Comment: Alternately, you can edit your routing table (on your local machine, not the VPN server) so that only a set of IP addresses use the VPN. Those settings depend upon which VPN client you are using. For example, Gnome's built-in VPN clinet makes such editing very easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an Ubuntu or Linux expert in no way but research this a lot last yeat and i have a solution that works pretty well for me.

Get the network information of the VM before connecting to your VPN client

`ifconfig`

```
ens4      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 42:01:0a:8a:00:04  
          inet addr:10.138.0.4  Bcast:10.138.0.4  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: fe80::4001:aff:fe8a:4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1460  Metric:1
          RX packets:1981508 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1035619 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:12219837340 (12.2 GB)  TX bytes:3879977314 (3.8 GB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:56603 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:56603 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:30401852 (30.4 MB)  TX bytes:30401852 (30.4 MB)
```

Take note of the adapter and IP Address, since GCP is wired you will have to get the subnet directly from GCP Portal.

[image: Image 1]

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0wfS.png)

Once you have IP/Network infromation the work begins.

1. Backup route table and add a VPNBypass to existing table.

   ```
   sudo su
   cp /etc/iproute2/rt_tables /etc/iproute2/rt_tables_orig
   echo "250   vpnbypass" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
   exit
   ```

   Use `cat /etc/iproute2/rt_tables` to confirm bypass entry in `rt_table`.

   Make sure the entry is inthere before you proceed.
2. Update the **vpnbypass** table to bypass VPN for subnet communication

   Note that i am using the subnet and Ethernet name to add the rule to the vpnbypass table

   ```
   sudo ip rule add from 10.138.0.0/20 table vpnbypass #Allow communication from Subnet
   sudo ip rule add to 10.138.0.0/20 table vpnbypass  #Allow communication to Subnet
   sudo ip rule add to 169.254.169.254 table vpnbypass  #Allow communication to Metadata Service
   sudo ip route add table vpnbypass to 10.138.0.0/20 dev ens4 #Selecting route for vpnbypass table
   sudo ip route add table vpnbypass default via 10.138.0.1 dev ens4 #selecting gateway
   ```
3. Connect to your VPN, the connection should not drop.  You can use `curl ipinfo.io` to confirm you are on VPN.

**OPTIONAL**

You can edit tthe `rc.local` file to make sure configuration is re-apply on reboot.

`sudo vi /etc/rc.local`

Add the following lines to the file

```
sudo ip rule add from 10.138.0.0/20 table vpnbypass #Allow communication from Subnet
sudo ip rule add to 10.138.0.0/20 table vpnbypass  #Allow communication to Subnet
sudo ip rule add to 169.254.169.254 table vpnbypass  #Allow communication to Metadata Service
sudo ip route add table vpnbypass to 10.138.0.0/20 dev ens4 #Selecting route for vpnbypass table
sudo ip route add table vpnbypass default via 10.138.0.1 dev ens4 #selecting gateway
```

Comment: This helped, thanks alot man! that's what i was looking for !